# HTML and CSS: do they share the same W3C Technical Report Development Process?

Tags: html, css, specifications, w3c

**Discovery:**
Looking at MDN specifications sections for both `html` elements and `css` properties W3C appear to share the same specification statuses.

**Investigation:**
Further investigation seems to lead to the same process document for both `html` and `css`, sub-section 6 ([W3C Technical Report Development Process](https://www.w3.org/2019/Process-20190301/#Reports)) outline the same recommendation statuses.

**Confirmation:** 
Does W3C share the same recommendation statuses for both `html` and `css` in their specifications, and if not what are the differences and can official sources be provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the W3C's HTML [Memorandum of Understanding Between W3C and WHATWG](https://www.w3.org/2019/04/WHATWG-W3C-MOU.html) there are no W3C HTML Working Drafts. Otherwise, they are the same.

Comment: Good to see we're moving forward with Living Standards for HTML